# Using postman and php image saving

Tags: php

I am making an API to upload image in a folder using postman. I am using form-data in postman to send image. I am using PHP to save image in a folder and path in database .

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to make an API to upload image in a folder at server side and and save its path in database.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image using REST API please try executing following code snippet which returns path of image upon success.

Also as an alternate solution try to send base64 encoded image data in request payload instead of multipart form data

```
function saveImage($data, $filename) {

    $base64_img_array = explode(':', $data);

    $img_info = explode(',', end($base64_img_array));
    $img_file_extension = '';
    if (!empty($img_info)) {
        switch ($img_info[0]) {
            case 'image/jpeg;base64':
                $img_file_extension = 'jpeg';
                break;
            case 'image/jpg;base64':
                $img_file_extension = 'jpg';
                break;
            case 'image/gif;base64':
                $img_file_extension = 'gif';
                break;
            case 'image/png;base64':
                $img_file_extension = 'png';
                break;
        }
    }
    $img_file_name = 'assets/images/' . $filename . '.' . $img_file_extension;    
    $img_file = file_put_contents($img_file_name, base64_decode($img_info[1]));

    if ($img_file) {
        return $img_file_name;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```